# Docker container /etc/hosts resolve ID

Tags: docker

My example: I have 100 containers running. At one point, 50 of them call "http://partner/greet" (this cannot be changed).
I want these 50 containters to know "where" each of them can find their corresponding partner-container (the other 50). It'a a 1:1 relationship.

When running a container with `docker run`, I know that I can add an IP Address to a Hostname with the `--add-host` option. So for 50 containers, I mapped the corresponding parnter container IPv4 to 'partner'.

But my problem is: **Container IPs are not static**. When a container restarts, it's IP Address can change. This is a big problem.

My containers can reach each other via `ping <id>` and `ping <name>`.
But when I tried adding the ID instead of the IP Adress to the hostfile, i got an error: The ID is not a valid IP Address (of course not).

I need something that lets me map the ID or the name of a container to "partner", so these URL calls work. How do I do it? Is that even possible?

Comment: why not create a shared network and give each container a name, and then you can use the container name as a DNS name to map the containers?

Comment: @yamenk I actually have them in a shared network already, but how do I map the container name to 'partner' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is the `--link` option when starting a container:

> --link=CONTAINER_NAME or ID:ALIAS
>
> Using this option as you run a container gives the new container's
>   /etc/hosts an extra entry named ALIAS that points to the IP address of
>   the container identified by CONTAINER_NAME_or_ID. This lets processes
>   inside the new container connect to the hostname ALIAS without having
>   to know its IP. The --link= option is discussed in more detail below.
>   Because Docker may assign a different IP address to the linked
>   containers on restart, Docker updates the ALIAS entry in the
>   /etc/hosts file of the recipient containers.

You can basically link the container to its partner when starting the container using the command:

```
docker run <partner-container-name>:partner ...
```

Thus in the container, `partner` will resolve to the partner container IP and you don't have to hardcode IP addresses.